# How to install custom fonts with tailwind and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, tailwind-css, custom-font

I am using Ruby on Rails and Tailwind and I want to install custom fonts, which I download and put into the folder /public/fonts/Barcelony.ttf

I see the font working in Chrome and Opera, but it does not work in Firefox and Safari.

I import base.scss into my application.scss file: @import "components/base";

add the following code to base.scss:

```
.font-barcelony {
  font-family: "BarcelonyRegular", Helvetica, Arial, serif;
}
```

How to make it work on all browsers?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but this should work:

main.scss:

```
@layer base {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'barcelony';
        src: url('/public/fonts/Barcelony.ttf') format('ttf'),
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'barcelony': ['barcelony', 'serif'],
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was a good start for me. A couple of notes, I think the `src` line should end with a `;` and the format value should be `truetype` instead of `ttf` (or at least that's what worked for me)